# How do I un-namespace a ruby constant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wash-out

I am using a library that doesn't handle namespaced models.  I have a rails engine that has all the ActiveRecord models that I need to use and as such I reference them with the namespace of the engine, ex: TableEngine::Posts.

Is there a way in Ruby to un-namespace the Posts class?

something like

```
TableEngine::Posts.demodulize # => Posts
```

Comment: Could you create a class that extends the module-ized class, or create a constant that is set to the module-ized class? It seems a little wonky and might break in other spectacular ways, I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first you can add the constant you need and assign the Class/Module to it (remember both are just objects). You should duplicate it to reset the name:

```
Posts = TableEngine::Posts.dup
```

Afterwards remove the source constant name:

```
Object.send :remove_const, :TableEngine
```

Then:

```
Posts
# => Posts
TableEngine
# => NameError: uninitialized constant TableEngine
TableEngine::Posts
# => NameError: uninitialized constant TableEngine
```

**UPDATE**. Why `dup` is needed:

Notice, the `class SomeClass` is a shortcut for creating an object of type `Class` and assigning it to some constant:

```
SomeClass = Class.new
```

When you create a class, its name value isn't set:

```
klass = Class.new
# => #<Class:0x00000001545a28>
klass.name
# => nil
```

When you assign it to the constant for the first time, the name is assigned and memoized:

```
Klass = klass
# => Klass
klass.name
# => "Klass"
```

When you later assign the object of type `Class` to another constant, it remains just the same object, referred by both constants:

```
NewKlass = Klass
# => Klass
Klass.name
# => "Klass"
NewKlass.name
# => "Klass"
```

That's why even if the initial constant will be removed, the object will keep carrying the old name.

```
Object.send :remove_const, :Klass
# => Klass
NewKlass
# => Klass
NewKlass.name
# => "Klass"

Klass
# => NameError: uninitialized constant Klass
```

The object by itself hasn't been changed. What has been changed is the list of constants, carried by the `Object` object.

When you duplicate the object of type `Class` it is created without any name (it is the new object):

```
new_klass = NewKlass.dup
# => #<Class:0x000000016ced90>
new_klass.name
# => nil
```

And when you assing it to the new constant, the name is set. That is how in the very first example above it receives the new name:

```
Posts = TableEngine::Posts.dup
# => Post
```

Comment: Why `dup` it when you remove the reference to the original and thus make it eligible for garbage collection anyway? In fact, even if you didn't remove the reference, I don't see why would want to `dup` the class.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the solution suggested by @Andrew with one slight change:

```
::Posts = TableEngine::Posts.dup
```

Adding the '::' prevented the Posts class from being namespaced by the context within which it was created, ex:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
    Posts = TableEngine::Posts.dup # => PostsController::Posts
    ::Posts = TableEngine::Posts.dup # => Posts
end
```